# How to write junits for lamda expression

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I have a piece of code for which I need to write junits. I am not understanding how to write for the statement "return(a,b) -> ". Please help me out in this because the statement inside this return(a,b)-> are not executing when I run its Junit

```
public GlobalFilter xyz() {
  String xyz = ""
  return (a, b) -> { 
    List<String> abc = a.getRequest().getHeaders().get(xyz);
    // Checking for empty value. If empty then returning 401 status code
    if (abc.equals("")) {
      // setting and returning a status code 401
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test, call `xyz` method, and get your `GlobalFilter` instance (the lambda expression). 
And then on that one you can run your test on this instance, same as any other unit test. for example:

```
GlobalFilter testedFilter = testedClass.xyz();
.. init mocks 
Mono<Void> mono = testedFilter.filter(mockExchange, mockChain);
.. verification and assertions
```

Comment: xyz is not a method its a variable with null value

Comment: @Anu from your code it seems xyz is both a method and variable